# Alojamento Web ou Alojamento Streaming?

Tags: lado-do-servidor, cliente-servidor, servidor, hospedagem

Estou a desenvolver um projeto, no qual a ideia é permitir ao utilizador ouvir (a partir de um player -> plugin em javaSript embutido na pagina index.php) a musica selecionada... No sentido de prestar um bom serviço, qual a solução ideal de alojamento para a reprodução de ficheiros MP3/audio alojados no Servidor Web? Tendo em conta o lado-servidor e lado-cliente.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que você terá outras variáveis como proteção de direitos autorais, mas então não existe uma resposta rápida para "qual a melhor solução", mas sim, qual a solução ideal para seu caso.

Acredito que você pode começar oferecendo o arquivo `mp3` com
`Content-Type: audio/mpeg`
 conforme a sugestão [nesta outra resposta](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/38951/is-it-possible-to-stream-music-video-from-an-apache-server) e evoluir seu sistema a ponto de utilizar um protocolo diferente do http e entregar o serviço por streaming.

Comment: Desculpa não ter mencionado o player (plugin em javaScript) que está embutido na página.
Sim, tenho em consideração a proteção de direitos autorais...
A ideia não é oferecer fisicamente o arquivo mp3, mas sim reproduzir, no lado-cliente a música selecionada.

Comment: E precisará evitar que o usuário armazene os arquivos, evitando que possa distribuir? Se a resposta for sim, você terá que adotar serviço por streaming.

Comment: Sim, os downloads não são permitidos... Mas, confesso que  agora fiquei confuso... Como é possível um utilizador, mal intencionado ou não, fazer o download das músicas? De forma a que consigas perceber, será que posso deixar aqui nos comentários um excerto do código fonte da pagina em causa? Bom não tenciono misturar os assuntos... mas, está tudo relacionado.

Comment: Acho melhor você separar o assunto em outra pergunta

Comment: Exato, acabei de criar uma nova pergunta, e que pode ser encontrada em:
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25820/como-evitar-que-um-utilizador-armazene-os-arquivos-mp3-evitando-assim-que-os-po

Comment: E esta pergunta você considera respondida?

Comment: Sim, para além de me alertar para o facto de proteger o conteúdo (ficheiros mp3), evitado dessa forma o download.
Agradeço a tua disponibilidade. No entanto, julgo que é uma matéria que ainda não está fechada.