# Como evitar que um utilizador armazene os arquivos mp3, evitando assim que os possa distribuir?

Tags: segurança, download, hospedagem

Antes de mais, é bom referir que a minha dúvida surge no seguimento de uma outra pergunta que coloquei aqui no stackoverflow em pt e que pode ser lida em: [Alojamento Web ou Alojamento Streaming?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25795/alojamento-web-ou-alojamento-streaming)

Estou a desenvolver um projecto que permite ao utilizador ouvir (através de um plugin javaScript) músicas selecionadas... As músicas/os ficheiros mp3 estão armazenados no Servidor numa diretoria designada de "uploads". A ideia é impedir que os ficheiros mp3 não sejam armazenados pelo utilizador que usufrua do serviço...

Segue um excerto do código fonte da pagina que é enviado ao browser:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugin_player.js"></script>

<!--Front-End -->

<h2>Músicas</h2>

<div style='' class='main_thumbnails' id='mainThumbnailsHolder'>
    <div style='' class='thumbnail-wrapper'>
      <img style='width:100%;' alt='...' src='./uploads/1405414353.jpg' border='0'/>
      <button></button>
      <div style='width:100%;' class='info-thumbanail'>
        Artista: ... </br>Genero: ... </br>Tempo: ... </br>Publicado: ... </br>
      </div>
</div>
<div style='' class='thumbnail-wrapper'>
      <img style='width:100%;' alt='...' src='./uploads/1405413192.jpg' border='0'/>
      <button></button>
      <div style='width:100%;' class='info-thumbanail'>
        Artista: ... <br>Genero: ...<br>Tempo: ...<br>Publicado: ... <br>
      </div>
</div>
<!-- etc. -->
</div>


<!-- "Interface" onde o player (plugin javaScript)  irá "beber" as dados... -->
<ul id='playlists' style='display:none;'>
 <li data-source='playlist1' data-thumbnail-path='#'></li>
</ul>

<ul id='playlist1' style='display:none;'>
   <li data-path='uploads/1405414353.mp3' data-thumbpath='uploads/1405414353.jpg' data-      downloadable='no' data-duration='1:19:31'>string<p>
    <span style='font-weitgth:bold;'> ::.....:: </span> - ::.Artista.:: </p>
   </li>
   <li data-path='uploads/1405413192.mp3' data-thumbpath='uploads/1405413192.jpg' data-downloadable='no' data-duration='3:19'>string<p>
    <span style='font-weitgth:bold;'> ::.....:: </span> - ::.Artista.:: </p>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Não sei se me fiz entender, pois a segurança dos conteúdos nos servidores é uma área muito complexa.

Comment: Se um sistema por javascript consegue obter, então qualquer utilizador consegue. Pode experimentar fazer um servidor de streaming em vez de armazenar diretamente em arquivos. E ainda assim, ele pode meramente gravar o áudio do PC.

Comment: Provavelmente só utilizando um player próprio e codificando a informação de maneira diferente da tradicional (ou criptografando, ou utilizando formatos não padrão). E mesmo assim, ainda pode ser feita uma gravação digital utilizando-se uma saída de áudio virtual no pc.

Answer (score 2):

Resposta curta: impossível de fazer. Se o utilizador consegue ouvir o áudio em seu computador, ele consegue armazenar uma cópia.

Detalhando: no caso mais extremo, o utilizador pode conectar a saída de áudio de sua placa de som à entrada de áudio de outra placa de som e gravar todo o som, criando assim seu próprio MP3.

Em casos menos extremos, o utilizador pode recuperar o áudio baixado que esteja armazenado em algum cache, ou capturar o streaming de áudio que foi feito, e salvar um arquivo MP3. Mesmo que você proteja isto por criptografia, que precise de um programa específico seu no computador do utilizador, ele simplesmente pode ir ao caso anterior.

Caso isto não seja problema para você, ou seja, você possa aceitar que alguns utilizadores salvem os áudios ou que os utilizadores façam alguma engenharia reversa em seu programa, e assim possam quebrar sua criptografia, você poderia fazer o seguinte:

- um plugin javascript, a ser rodado pelo utilizador, que gere um par de chaves pública-privada
- o plugin envia a chave publica ao seu servidor
- seu servidor lista os parâmetros de música para o utilizador escolher
- quando o utilizador escolher a música, seu servidor gera uma chave simétrica aleatória, criptografa ela com a chave pública do utilizador, e manda para o utilizador
- o utilizador recebe a chave simétrica, descriptografa ela, e fica com ela em memória
- seu servidor manda o áudio (streaming) criptografado com a chave simétrica para o utilizador.
- utilizador receber este streaming e descriptografa com a chave simétrica que recebeu.
- o plugin toca a música.

E cada vez que um utilizador for utilizar seu serviço, ele faz todo o processo de trocar as chaves e criptografar.

Comment: Agradeço, as informações.
Mas, não é demais referir que a minha dúvida surge no seguimento de uma outra pergunta que coloquei aqui no stackoverflow em pt e que pode ser lida em: 
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25795/alojamento-web-ou-alojamento-streaming

Comment: hum, edite sua pergunta original e coloque isto: que vc já fez outra pergunta, e pelas respostas dela, vc tem a seguinte dúvida: e aí vem sua pergunta acima. Fica mais fácil para outros saberem