# Bloquear download de arquivos no IIS

Tags: iis, web.config

Estou tentando bloquear o *download* das músicas da minha aplicação.
Tentei bloquear colocando um arquivo `web.config` na pasta com as músicas com as configurações abaixo:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Mas, ele ainda acessa a pasta e permite o download das músicas.

Comment: Pode descrever sua aplicação? Como ela funciona, onde ficam os arquivos de música, como esse acesso direto pode ser feito.

Comment: Entende-se que download é mais do que abrir o gerenciador de downloads, o download é até mesmo reproduzir um arquivo online em um player usando a tag `<audio>`, você quer que quando a pessoa clique na musica ele abra o player diretamente? Ou você quer proteger o acesso da musica contra copias?

Comment: Oi pessoal, eu queria bloquear o acesso contra cópias... Eu tenho o player JPlayer em um html que chama as musicas dessa forma `<audio id="jp_audio_0" preload="metadata" src="player/musicas/minha_musica.mp3" title=""></audio>`, eu tentei usar a configuração de segurança do web.config só que ai nem o player toca mais as músicas.

Comment: primeiramente muito obrigado por me ajudarem. Eu acabei achando essa resposta: (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25820/como-evitar-que-um-utilizador-armazene-os-arquivos-mp3-evitando-assim-que-os-po) e a conclusão é de que é impossível impedir o download das músicas, o que eu posso fazer é dar uma dificultada... Valeu.

Answer (score 0):

**Taís**, se o seu site fornece a reprodução de músicas (audio) e você quer bloquear o download das mesmas (pelo código fonte, por exemplo), será necessário um script (no seu caso, aspx eu imagino) interceptando a requisição dos ".mp3" para checar a referência (ou quaisquer outras validações) liberando ou não a continuação do "despejo" binário do arquivo de mídia.

Ex.: `seu-site-de-musica.com/player.aspx?musica=10`

Onde `10` é o ID da música no banco e `player.aspx` verifica a referência da requisição (ex.: Se não vier do host **seu-site-de-musica.com**, então, bloquear o acesso).

Ou então, para fazer com que o `web.config` bloqueie acesso a arquivos .mp3 (ou demais extensões):

**web.config**:

```
<system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="*" path="*.mp3" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" />
    </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

Mais informações: 
http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering

Comment: Felipe, eu só criei uma página **.html** na pasta **player/** e usei o pluggin JPlayer para tocar as musicas que estão na pasta **player/musicas/**, não tenho banco de dados para utilizar.

Comment: @Taís, entendi. Neste caso você pode utilizar o **web.config** acima e testar o seu download? Se não funcionar, tente mudar o `path="*.mp3"` para `path="player/musicas/*.mp3"`.

Comment: Ele bloqueou o download e o acesso a pasta... só que o player não toca mais... O player toca as músicas esse código `<audio id="jp_audio_0" preload="metadata" src="player/musicas/minha_musica.mp3" title=""></audio>`

Comment: @Tais, tente restringir o acesso aos arquivos .mp3 somente para o usuário da conta (Ex.: TaisUser): `<location path="player/musicas/*.mp3">
     <system.webServer>
         <security>
             <authorization>
                 <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
                 <add accessType="Allow" roles="TaisUser" />
             </authorization>
         </security>
     </system.webServer>
 </location>`

Comment: Não esqueça de remover as linhas que criamos antes do `web.config`. A idéia aqui é limitar o acesso ao arquivo ao DONO do arquivo (no caso `TaisUser`), ou seja, outro usuário (ex.: `IUSR`) não poderá acessar, já que não são donos (`IUSR`). Tente por favor.